# Apex heap size error - VF dowloading attachments

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits, heap, size

[image]I have one VF page from where I am trying to download some attachments - The time I tried to download attachments which includes Attachments of size 4 MB+ size, it start showing me this error.

> Exception : Apex Heap Size too large : 123454

It work fine in the Unlimited Edition.

I get that this is a Heap Size issue explained [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm)

I want to avoid getting this error message, i.e. I want to reset or reduce my Heap Size . Please provide me some suggestions or Example using which I can get it done.

Comment: Can you post your code so the community can better assist you?

Comment: Jeff Douglas did a great post on managing the heap.  Take a look at this link.  http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/08/16/managing-the-heap-in-salesforce-com/

Comment: To clarify, your screen shot looks like your users are selecting one or more attachments and then your code is to provide a convenient "single" zip download of them all?

Comment: @DougAyers : Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download attachment then can you use standard view url which saleaforce provides. There you would not face heap size issue.

Comment: Agree. If your users are just downloading attachments one-by-one then simply provide the `{!URLFOR( $Action.Attachment.View, attachment.id )}` of the file and let Salesforce stream the file through the user's browser -- no heap to manage in your code.

Comment: @DougAyers : No I want to let them download all selected files in zip. So I can not make use of Salesforce Download URL here.